Deserialize a json into an entity with Symfony Deserializer
I need to save a snapshot of an entity in a json field and I'm trying to deserialize it. The problem is that the result of the deserialization, has all the ID with null value. I dont want to insert all the setters for the ID in the entities.
How can i resolve this problem?
Post entity:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PostRepository::class)]
class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Comment::class, mappedBy: 'post')]
    private Collection $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): static
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->add($comment);
            $comment->setPost($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if ($this->comments->removeElement($comment)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getPost() === $this) {
                $comment->setPost(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

Comment entity:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CommentRepository::class)]
class Comment
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'comments')]
    private ?Post $post = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): static
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPost(): ?Post
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function setPost(?Post $post): static
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }
}

Comment SnapshotPost:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SnapshotPostRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SnapshotPostRepository::class)]
class SnapshotPost
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private string $json = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getJson(): string
    {
        return $this->json;
    }

    public function setJson(string $json): static
    {
        $this->json = $json;

        return $this;
    }
}

#[Route('/api')]
class TestController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(
        private readonly SnapshotPostRepository $snapshotPostRepository,
        private readonly PostRepository $postRepository
    )
    {
    }

    #[Route('/test', name: 'app_test')]
    public function index(SerializerInterface $serializer): JsonResponse
    {

        $snapshot = $this->snapshotPostRepository->find(1);
        echo 'Snapshot';
        dump($snapshot);
        
        $result = $serializer->deserialize($snapshot->getJson(), 'App\Entity\Post[]', 'json');


        echo 'deserialized';
        dump($result);

}



As I know, the Serializer Component works with public properties/methods. You should add:
public function setId(int $id)
{

}

However, you can try to use PropertyNormalizer. It uses reflection to get access to private properties.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#built-in-normalizers
